# PS2 Controller on Resident Evil 6

Tags: pc, controllers, resident-evil-6

I have an USB PS2 Controller and I would like to play Resident Evil 6 using it. Actually, the controller works, however, when I need to press a button, the game tells me to press buttons **"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"** instead of **"triangle, circle, x, square, L1, R1, L2, R2"**.

I would like to know if there is a way to fix it?

Also, I would like to know if the same issue would happen if I used an Xbox 360 controller?

Comment: There is no such issue with Xbox 360/Xbox One controllers, the game features Xbox button prompts.